# Learning Python: simple functions to write

Tags: python

I'm starting to learn Python, and I would love to "test" myself with a series of simple challenges.  Things like "write a function that sorts a list alphabetically", "write a function to convert underscore-separated strings into camel-case", etc. I'm basically looking for a series of problems to work my way through as I wrap my head around Python (think CS 101 homework assignments): either a list of 10-15 ideas, or a link to one.

Bonus points for stuff that specifically makes use Python's unique features like tuples, generators, etc.  A nod in the right direction for each problem wouldn't go amiss, either.

Comment: Try searching Stack Overflow for the exact thing you're asking for.  That's always a good way to learn what others have already asked.

Comment: You might enjoy doing it in test-driven style: just add examples that should work to the function docstring, and call doctest.testmod() to check them.  Then, work on the code until the tests pass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beginner-level:

http://codingbat.com/python

All other levels:

http://projecteuler.net/

Answer (score 6):

http://projecteuler.net/ and with http://www.pythonchallenge.com/, off you go! :)

Oh, I forgot my favourite: https://github.com/gregmalcolm/python_koans

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to reverse the key-value relationship in a dictionary. This is tricky because you have to decide how to handle situations like unhashable values and duplicate values.

Check out the infinite iterators in [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) and write some of your own with funny properties. Examples: continually choose random items from a sequence, emit prime numbers, do a random walk.

Use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to get interesting data from the web.